# Can't open new activity in android studio after cloning from github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

These are the only options that are available. I cannot create a new xml file or a new activity.

What should I do next? I tried updating the SDK, restoring default settings, but nothing seems to work. Does it have anything to do with git, or is the problem in android studio?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.